# Probability of two uniform random numbers being more than $\frac{1}{2}$ apart

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

Two numbers are chosen randomly and independently from the unit interval $(0,1)$. 
 What is the probability that they differ by more than $\frac{1}{2}$? 
Hint: Think of the $2$ numbers chosen as coordinates in the Cartesian plane. Draw a square with vertices at $(0,0)$,$(1,0)$,$(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$. Allowable choices for the $2$ points lie below the line $y=x-\frac{1}{2}$ or the above $y=x+\frac{1}{2}$. Find the combined area of these regions. 
 I need help on this. I know what $y=x-\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=x+\frac{1}{2}$ looks like but I am not understanding the problem as a whole

Comment: A did a simulation of $10^7$ trials and it seems that the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: how did you construct it? This hint was included in my question

Comment: I just used a random generator, generated pairs and counted how often the difference is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I never learned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that the two number chosen randomly from unit interval$(0, 1)$ is same as the conditions $0\lt x. y \lt 1$ .  Let the two numbers be $x, y$ Then the probability is that $|x-y| \gt 0. 5$Draw the graph of the two functions and use geometric probability to get answer.

[image]

You need to just divide the sum of areas of two corner triangles with the square. It is easy to see probability is $0. 25$

Comment: never learned how to use geometric probability. The hint I was given, I drew the square and drew the lines but after that, I am confused

Comment: @behold Geometric probability is simply the ratio of favourable area with total area.

Comment: @behold check the edit

Comment: I see now. Thanks

Comment: the combined areas are the areas with both colored lines crossing?

Answer (score 2):

The square mentioned in the problem is the [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) of the problems, where every point represents some outcome of picking the two random numbers. The blue regions in the plot below shows the regions where, for some $x$, $|y-x|>\frac{1}{2}$, which is bounded by the two functions in the problem formulation. The area of these regions gives the sought probability.

[image]

Comment: thanks, so i can use any one of those points in the blue area?

Comment: Nice image. Can I ask what tool you made it with?

Comment: @mathreadler Sure! Mathematica :)

Comment: @behold Yes. The $x$ values are on the horizontal axis and $y$ on the other. Choose a value of $x$, say $x=0.$ Then you can see that all the points from $1/2$ to $1$ are valid values of $y$. Color this line. Then go on to the next $x$-value and determine which values of $y$ works. Do this for all values of $x$ on $(0,1)$. Then you get the regions.

Answer (score 1):

You have already had several answers but none with picture. A good practice is to try and visualize the problem with an image or graph or picture.

Here is a plot of the area you will want to integrate on your density function.

[image]

Comment: I am using the white area?

Comment: Guess we had the same idea, with 6 seconds between :)

Comment: @behold I explained the idea in my answer. You are "using" the black area. However, it seems that you don't fully understand the problem. Try picking some values of $x$ and then determining which values of $y$ that are then more than a half away from it. Then paint the resulting regions black. That is how you get the plot.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and $y$ are the variables, you require $$|x-y|>\frac 12$$
$$\implies x-y>\frac 12\cup x-y<-\frac 12$$

Hence the hint given

A simple diagram shows the area to be $\frac 14$

Comment: you used a union, I am not sure how to do that last part

Comment: Just read it as either...or...

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. You have to choose 2 numbers in (0,1). Now imagine that the first number , which is in [0,1] lies on the x axis and the 2nd number on the y axis. Now the 1st can be in between (0,0) and (1,0) and the 2nd can be in between (0,0) and (0,1).

Now suppose the first is some where in between [0,1] ( say 0.2) on x axis. Corresponding to this the number on the y axis can be in [0,1] on y axis (say 0.3).  So you get a point (0.2 , 0.3) in the x- y plane. Since these are real numbers they can be infinite in that interval. That is why we talk of the area of the region because it will account for all the points.

The line are just the constraint given in the question. Because the area has to between those.