# Tricky abstract thinking Math problem. Probability question including an equation.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Two values, $x$ and $y$ are selected at random and independently of each other from the interval. What is the probability.

The only idea I have thought of is using BinomPdf, but I still don't know how to implement that into this.

This is a question I am solving on my own that I have discovered. If you send the answer and work it would not assist me cheating or anything malicious.

Comment: tricky ... not trick

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Any ideas?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I am not sure what happened some of it deleted. It should be fixed now.

Comment: It's also covered at [(Question 2657076)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657076/whats-the-probability-of-choosing-two-numbers-from-0-1-and-having-the-diffe).

Comment: @Jam thank you. Can you confirm the answer is  0.25?

Comment: @GamingCobra That's correct.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2182328/638604 if I stated the equations and then say the probability is 0.25 would that be proper justification or is more info required. I want to show this to my teacher. (it is not a competition I discovered the question on my own and wanted to show it to my teacher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many questions in mathematics, the best way to start is by making a picture!

Consider the following image, which I stole from an example given by Peter Woolfitt in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100120/646141) to an unreleated question.

[image: Soltuion]

As noted in the original source:

> The [picture above] is the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $|x−y|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$

The answer you are looking for is precisely the proportion of area that is white. Can you figure out what this is?

Comment: How would I find the area in the white?

Comment: @GamingCobra Divide the square into four quadrants. Each white triangle occupies precisely half of the quadrant it lies in.

Comment: is the probability 0.25?

Comment: @GamingCobra That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

View the two numbers as coordinates of a point in the unit square.  The points of interest are above the line $y=x+\frac 12$ or below the line $y=x-\frac 12$.  That is two triangles.  Compute their total area and you have the probability as the area of the square is $1$.

Comment: How would I compute the total area? how did you get the probability? Could you share your full length work?

Comment: Just draw the picture of the square and the two lines.  They cut off two triangles which are the area you want.

Comment: is the probability 0.25?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The idea of points in the square is a useful one for many 2D distributions